# Merge Ordered Event Sequences into Table

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I'm searching for an algorithm that solves the following problem: Say I've got a collection of ordered event sequences and want to create table from them

```
AB
BC
```

leading to a table of the form

```
ABC
**
 **
```

the first line being the headers. For each input sequence I want a row with markers in the columns of the events that occured.

Another more complex example (with three sequences) would be:

```
AAB
BBA
CBA
```

leading to

```
CBBAAB
   ***
 ***  
** *
```

I know that sometimes there are multiple possible solutions (e.g. the trivial example of two sequences consisting only one event each I'm free to decide which comes first). I'm only interested in any solution, the resulting header sequence (`CBBAAB` in the last example) should be as short as possible.

Doe anyone know a algorithm that solves that problem?

Comment: Are the events just strings or characters like you show in your example?

Comment: The events are in fact strings. But since the number of different strings is limited I could map them to ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it could be solved in a much simpler way. The problem to me seems like finding first the shortest common supersequence and then to find markers - compute the common subsequence of each string with supersequence.

For example:

```
AAB

BBA

CBA
```

Shortest common supersequence between `AAB, BBA` is `BBAAB` or `AABBA`
then shortest supersequence between `BBAAB` and `CBA` is `CBBAAB` or between `AABBA` and `CBA` is `CAABBA`

Now to find markers for `AAB`, find the common subsequence between `CBBAAB` and `AAB`.
similarly for `BBA` and `CBBAAB` and as well for `CBA`, `CBBAAB`

Here are some links to help with finding them:

[Shortest common supersequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem)

[Longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem I'm trying to solve here is called (multiple) [sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment). It's quite common in bioinformatics (they are using it to compare DNA strings). There are a lot of tools for alignment of DNA strings, the number of generic tools however seems quite limited.

[noporpoise/seq-align](https://github.com/noporpoise/seq-align) on GitHub seems quite promising. I would have to build a couple of tools around it to adapt it for my purpose. My sequence elements are multiple characters but since I won't have that many I will be able to map them to ASCII chars. Also the tool only does pairwise sequence alignment so I will have to chain the calls. To find the optimum solution I would have to execute it for every possible chain (generate all permutations).